# PHP/Laravel: Storage::disk(). Delivers true, but should not

Tags: php, laravel, file, storage

Laravel 5.2
I dont get it. I am checking whether file exists in folder. There is no file, but I get `true`.

I have tried different approaches, such as:

```
Storage::disk('local')->exists($path_to_json . array_first($text['other'])); //true

Storage::disk('local')->has($path_to_json . array_first($text['other'])); //true

if(file_exists($path_to_json . array_first($text['other']))) //always false, even if file is there

dd($path_to_json) // "list/text-1a/"
```

`filesystems.php` is looking good, I can upload file to where I need it.

```
'default' => ('local'),
'disks' => [

    'local' => [
        'driver' => 'local',
        'root' => storage_path('app'),
    ],
```

Had someone the same issue? I've read some topics, guys having opposite situation, they get false while file is in folder.

UPDATE.
The "bug" is in `Storage::disk` logic, if I can say so. Or in my head.
`$text['other']` has `preg_grep`, which checks file extension. Exclude txt and png. 
`Storage::disk` sees, that there are txt files and retuns `TRUE`. But I was checking  for other files, that don't have txt or png. 
That is why validation have to be slightly refactored :

```
 Storage::disk('local')->exists($path_to_json . $id . '_datafile.json');
```

Here we are looking for a particular file with extension JSON. That was the issue. If I made myself clear, would be very happy.

Comment: clear the cache and try again

Comment: Check for hidden files maybe? Probably not the case but good to know.

Comment: @Naveen `php artisan cache:clear` ?

Comment: @HowardP nope, no hidden files.

Comment: try ```php artisan cache:clear```. is it works ? whats in ```$path_to_json```?

Comment: in $path_to_json is the path to directory in which has to be file. Look up in the Topic, I `dd` it.
I can't clear cache right now, will try it tomorow morning.

Comment: Show also value of `$text['other']`

Comment: `$others = preg_grep("/^(?!.*\.txt|.*\.png)/", $files);`
looking for extensions that differ from txt and png. 
`$text['other'] = $others;`